# How to get all columns from a SELECT DISTINCT query?

Tags: mysql, pdo, distinct

I'm using PDO with MySQL.

I want to select all rows from a given table with distinct values in a given column, but `SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table` returns the rows with only that column_name. Therefore I can't access the other row's columns.

I've been searching for answers and it looks like `SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table` is supposed to return all the rows with distinct values inside column_name **with all the row's columns**. However, I only get the column I want distinc'ed:

```
Array
    (
        [image] => leather_helmet.jpg
        // there are supposed to be more fields here...
    )
```

May this be a PDO's bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only 1 column distinct you have to think of which record you want for the other columns. For instance if you like the min `id` record for the distinct column then you can do

```
SELECT * 
FROM armor_unsealed
WHERE id IN 
(
   SELECT min(id) 
   FROM armor_unsealed
   WHERE piece=:piece 
   GROUP BY image 
)'
```

Comment: Hello! Can you explain the reasoning behind your answer please?

Comment: What values should be picked that are not distinct?

Comment: If I wanted distinct strings inside a varchar column, would I replace 'SELECT MIN(id)' for 'SELECT DISTINCT image'?

Comment: I changed the answer. You need a rule to tell the DB which record to pick. My query can be translated to this: *Take distinct images and then select the record with the lowest id for every image*

Comment: All columns, except the distinct one, should be returned. That is my problem: I sucessfully select the columns with distinct values in them, but then I can't access that row's other columns.

Comment: Try the query above. It selects all columns from a record.

Comment: Its almost there, but 'SELECT * FROM armor_unsealed
WHERE image IN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT image
  FROM armor_unsealed
  WHERE piece=:piece
  GROUP BY image
)' is not returning distinct image names, they repeat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38043/discussion-between-amoguai-and-juergen-d)